# ¿Cómo grabar una fotografía en Android y pasarla por WhatsApp?

Tags: android, whatsapp

Si me pueden ayudar tengo un código en el cual abro la cámara de `Android` y toma la fotografía y la paso a una `ImageView` pero ahora deseo grabarla en el teléfono para enviarla por WhatsAppy no encuentro como hacerlo, es un formulario de fotografías y deseo pasarlas todas, el código que uso es:

```
{
    public void GSMPICS1actual(View view) {
        picsgsms1actual = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picsgsms1actual);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 
    }

    public void GSMPICS2actual(View view) {
        picsgsms2actual = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picsgsms2actual);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode ==0) {
            super.onActivityResult(0, resultCode, data);
            Bitmap bitmappicsgsms1actual = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            picsgsms1actual.setImageBitmap(bitmappicsgsms1actual);

        } else if (requestCode ==1) {
            super.onActivityResult(1, resultCode, data);
            Bitmap bitmappicsgsms2actual = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            picsgsms2actual.setImageBitmap(bitmappicsgsms2actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "pasar" todas? una por una o todas en una sola acción?

Comment: todas en una acción